# Set background image in css style angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to set an image dynamically having the path of the image setted in a scope. The problem is that this is seen as a text, the value of selectedEvent.eventBannerImage is shown correctly, in my case the final url looks something like this:

background-image: url('/mydomain/images/banners\444b6e91-30fe-478b-a3d3-7984f0d35e69__1253402730_2873_full-269x300.jpg'), but it doesn't appear like a link as I need but just as a text. The image isn't shown.

```
<div style="background-image:    
    url('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/{{selectedEvent.eventBannerImage}}')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here: http://jsbin.com/zehawu/1/edit

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 
 'url({{pageContext.request.contextPath}}/images/{{selectedEvent.eventBannerImage}})'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a directive for the binding -- probably [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).  Unfortunately, `ng-style` takes an *expression*, not a *string*, so you can't use concatenation inside of it.

```
<div ng-style="ctrl.bgImage">

// In the controller:
this.bgImage = {"background-image": 
    "url(" + this.pageContext.request.contextPath
    + "/images/" + this.selectedEvent.eventBannerImage + ")"
};
```